# How do you format a currency to number when using React native EXPO?

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I take a number like $10,000.00 and have it output as 10000?

I followed numerous articles, all incomplete and none working.

I don't need full internationalization, just the ability to format a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex.

Please try below code.

```
var currency = "$10,000.00";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

console.log('Number => ', number)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this code is very specific to 9 characters. I wanted some flexibility with the code such that any number with currency can be converted to a number.

Comment: It's not specific to 9 characters. It will work with any currency string with any number. https://prnt.sc/rzl6bj